# Mysql, How do I add a computed column to compute the sum of a json column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Column `a` contains a json array formatted like `[1,4,3,6]`

I want column `b` to be a sum of column `a`.

```
ALTER TABLE `T` ADD `b` int AS 
        (SELECT SUM(t.c) FROM JSON_TABLE(a, '$[*]' COLUMNS (c INT PATH '$')) AS t) NULL;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(t.c) FROM JSON_TABLE(a, '$[*]' COLUMNS (c INT PATH '$')) AS t) NULL' at line 1

Comment: Might want to look at [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) here, alter table does things to the columns once and not when an event occurs (such as insert, update etc.)

Comment: does the select run and produce expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html#:%7E:text=Subqueries%20are%20not%20permitted) of the MySQL docs specifies the rules for generated columns. The two which seem most relevant here are:

> - Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted.
> - Subqueries are not permitted.

You could achieve *"similar"* functionality with a pair of triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `test_t_b_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `t`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.b = (SELECT SUM(t.c) FROM JSON_TABLE(NEW.a, '$[*]' COLUMNS (c INT PATH '$')) AS t);
  END$$

CREATE TRIGGER `test_t_b_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `t`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NOT OLD.a <=> NEW.a THEN
        SET NEW.b = (SELECT SUM(t.c) FROM JSON_TABLE(NEW.a, '$[*]' COLUMNS (c INT PATH '$')) AS t);
    END IF;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```